# Python training a model tensorflow GPU/CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm starting to learn basic AI training with Python. I have GTX 1660 super and I'm unfamiliar with this kind of errors.

```
python3 script.py

2023-04-06 02:52:55.006577: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-04-06 02:52:55.530873: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2023-04-06 02:53:22.397417: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:996] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2023-04-06 02:53:22.426155: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1956] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
Epoch 1/10
 8323/15626 [==============>...............] - ETA: 4:42 - loss: 0.8635
```

This is the output of this command :

`python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"`

```
2023-04-06 03:00:07.843536: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-04-06 03:00:09.830835: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2023-04-06 03:00:12.960057: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:996] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2023-04-06 03:00:13.010737: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:996] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2023-04-06 03:00:13.010992: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:996] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

I did everything that's written at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu, i have latest drivers and CUDA installed. I'm not sure does this mean my CPU or GPU is used ?

Comment: So it tells you to install TensorRT, not sure what this is but must be important. Also, usually the easiest way to work with TF locally is in a Docker container since containers come with fully functional TF/CUDA install. See this: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker

Comment: @NotAName No, TensorRT is not important for GPU support.

Comment: Hi @Haxor Flux, Please provide us some more details like the installed TensorFlow, Python version and which system OS you are using.